# How to grab only values from SQL Server PYODBC query?

Tags: python, sql, dictionary, pyodbc

I have a python script where I'd like to  append only a couple of items to a top level dictionary in a JSON object. However, there are inner dictionaries where I need to append not the column name, but the value only.  To make it easier, I would just like the values to be appended to my already hardcoded keys.  Here is an example of my script.

```
import pyodbc
import json
import collections
import requests
import time
import logging
import httplib
import datetime
import logging
import logging.handlers


start = time.time()
pyFC = "SCData.DBO.SO_SC_1"

connstr = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=server;DATABASE=SCData; UID=;PWD=
conn = pyodbc.connect(connstr)
cursor = conn.cursor()
FN_SRNumber = "SRNumber"
lFields = [""]

#lFields = ["SRNumber"]
sFields = ""


for fld in lFields:
    if(sFields==""):
        sFields = fld
    else:
        sFields = sFields + "," + fld


#sSQL = "SELECT SRNumber FROM {}".format(pyFC)
# sSQL = "SELECT {} FROM {}".format(sFields, pyFC)
cursor.execute("""SELECT SRNumber, last_edited_user, ITEM_1,ITEM_2,ITEM_3,ITEM_4,ITEM_5,ITEM_6,ITEM_7,ITEM_8,ITEM_9,ITEM_10, QYT_1,QYT_2,QYT_3,QYT_4,QYT_5,QTY_6,QTY_7,QTY_8,QTY_9,QTY_10, RESOLUTION_CODE
FROM SO_SC_1
WHERE SRNumber LIKE '%1-%'""")
# cursor.execute(sSQL)



columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
#columns = lFields
ii = 0
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    lResults = []    #make sure lResults are initiated here
    lValues = []
    for i in range(len(columns)):
        lValues.append( str(row[i]))
    SRNumber =  lValues[0]
    driverfirst = lValues [1]
    # BulkyItem1 = lValues [2]
    # BulkyItem2 = lValues [2]
    # BulkyItem3 = lValues [3]
    # BulkyItem4 = lValues [4]
    # BulkyItem5 = lValues [5]
    # BulkyItem6 = lValues [6]
    # BulkyItem7 = lValues [7]
    # BulkyItem8 = lValues [8]
    # BulkyItem9 = lValues [9]
    # BulkyItem10 = lValues [10]
    BulkyQ1 = lValues [11]
    # BulkyQ2 = lValues [12]
    # BulkyQ3 = lValues [13]
    # BulkyQ4 = lValues [14]
    # BulkyQ5 = lValues [15]
    # BulkyQ6 = lValues [16]
    # BulkyQ7 = lValues [17]
    # BulkyQ8 = lValues [18]
    # BulkyQ9 = lValues [19]
    # BulkyQ1 = lValues [20]
    ResCode = lValues [21]

    #dResult = dict(zip(columns, row))
    dResult = dict(zip(columns, lValues))
    # Adding additional items  ******************************
    dResult.setdefault("ResolutionCode", ResCode )
    dResult.setdefault("UpdatedByUserLogin", 'MYLA-SAN2')
    #dResult.setdefault("ListOfLa311ElectronicWaste", dict())

    l311 = []
    d = dict()
    d.setdefault("DriverFirstName", driverfirst )
    d.setdefault("DriverLastName","placeholder" )
    d.setdefault("BulkyItemType", "Basketball Set" )
    # d.setdefault("BulkyItemCount", BulkyQ1)
    d.setdefault("Name", "061020150957233612")
    d.setdefault("BulkyItemCount", BulkyQ1 )
    l311.append(d)
    d = dict()
    d.setdefault("DriverFirstName", driverfirst)
    d.setdefault("DriverLastName", "West")
    d.setdefault("BulkyItemType", "Basketball Set")
    d.setdefault("Type", "Bulky Item")
    d.setdefault("BulkyItemCount", 2)
    l311.append(d)
    d.setdefault("DriverFirstName", "Geoffrey")
    d.setdefault("DriverLastName", "West")
    d.setdefault("BulkyItemType", "Basketball Set")
    d.setdefault("Type", "Bulky Item")
    d.setdefault("BulkyItemCount", 2)
    l311.append(d)
    d.setdefault("DriverFirstName", "Geoffrey")
    d.setdefault("DriverLastName", "West")
    d.setdefault("BulkyItemType", "Basketball Set")
    d.setdefault("Type", "Bulky Item")
    d.setdefault("BulkyItemCount", 2)
    l311.append(d)
    d.setdefault("DriverLastName", "West")
    d.setdefault("BulkyItemType", "Basketball Set")
    d.setdefault("Type", "Bulky Item")
    d.setdefault("BulkyItemCount", 2)
    l311.append(d)
    d.setdefault("DriverFirstName", "Geoffrey")
    d.setdefault("DriverLastName", "West")
    d.setdefault("BulkyItemType", "Basketball Set")
    d.setdefault("Type", "Bulky Item")
    d.setdefault("BulkyItemCount", 2)
    l311.append(d)
    d.setdefault("DriverFirstName", "Geoffrey")
    d.setdefault("DriverLastName", "West")
    d.setdefault("BulkyItemType", "Basketball Set")
    d.setdefault("Type", "Bulky Item")
    d.setdefault("BulkyItemCount", 2)
    l311.append(d)
    d.setdefault("DriverFirstName", "Geoffrey")
    d.setdefault("DriverLastName", "West")
    d.setdefault("BulkyItemType", "Basketball Set")
    d.setdefault("Type", "Bulky Item")
    d.setdefault("BulkyItemCount", 2)
    l311.append(d)
    d.setdefault("DriverFirstName", "Geoffrey")
    d.setdefault("DriverLastName", "West")
    d.setdefault("BulkyItemType", "Basketball Set")
    d.setdefault("Type", "Bulky Item")
    d.setdefault("BulkyItemCount", 2)
    l311.append(d)
    d.setdefault("DriverFirstName", "Geoffrey")
    d.setdefault("DriverLastName", "West")
    d.setdefault("BulkyItemType", "Basketball Set")
    d.setdefault("Type", "Bulky Item")
    d.setdefault("BulkyItemCount", 2)
    l311.append(d)



    dL311 = dict()
    dL311.setdefault("BulkyItem", l311)
    dResult.setdefault("ListOfLa311BulkyItem",dL311)
    dOthers = dict()
    #Adding empty dictionaries;
    dResult.setdefault("ListOfLa311IllegalDumpingPickup", dOthers)
    dResult.setdefault("ListOfLa311ManualPickup", dOthers)
    dResult.setdefault("ListOfLa311MetalHouseholdAppliancesPickup", dOthers)
    dResult.setdefault("ListOfLa311MoveInMoveOut", dOthers)
    dResult.setdefault("ListOfLa311ServiceNotComplete", dOthers)
    #Ends of adding additional itmes ****************************************
    lResults.append({"MetaData": {}, "SRData": dResult})
    print lResults
```

Output:

```
{
    "MetaData": {},
    "SRData": {
        "ITEM_1": "None",
        "ITEM_10": "None",
        "ITEM_2": "None",
        "ITEM_3": "None",
        "ITEM_4": "None",
        "ITEM_5": "None",
        "ITEM_6": "None",
        "ITEM_7": "None",
        "ITEM_8": "None",
        "ITEM_9": "None",
        "ListOfLa311BulkyItem": {
            "BulkyItem": [
                {
                    "BulkyItemCount": "None",
                    "BulkyItemType": "Basketball Set",
                    "DriverFirstName": "SA",
                    "DriverLastName": "placeholder",
                    "Name": "061020150957233612"
                },
                {
                    "BulkyItemCount": 2,
                    "BulkyItemType": "Basketball Set",
                    "DriverFirstName": "SA",
                    "DriverLastName": "West",
                    "Type": "Bulky Item"
                },
                {
                    "BulkyItemCount": 2,
                    "BulkyItemType": "Basketball Set",
                    "DriverFirstName": "SA",
                    "DriverLastName": "West",
                    "Type": "Bulky Item"
                },
                {
                    "BulkyItemCount": 2,
                    "BulkyItemType": "Basketball Set",
                    "DriverFirstName": "SA",
                    "DriverLastName": "West",
                    "Type": "Bulky Item"
                },
                {
                    "BulkyItemCount": 2,
                    "BulkyItemType": "Basketball Set",
                    "DriverFirstName": "SA",
                    "DriverLastName": "West",
                    "Type": "Bulky Item"
                },
                {
                    "BulkyItemCount": 2,
                    "BulkyItemType": "Basketball Set",
                    "DriverFirstName": "SA",
                    "DriverLastName": "West",
                    "Type": "Bulky Item"
                },
                {
                    "BulkyItemCount": 2,
                    "BulkyItemType": "Basketball Set",
                    "DriverFirstName": "SA",
                    "DriverLastName": "West",
                    "Type": "Bulky Item"
                },
                {
                    "BulkyItemCount": 2,
                    "BulkyItemType": "Basketball Set",
                    "DriverFirstName": "SA",
                    "DriverLastName": "West",
                    "Type": "Bulky Item"
                },
                {
                    "BulkyItemCount": 2,
                    "BulkyItemType": "Basketball Set",
                    "DriverFirstName": "SA",
                    "DriverLastName": "West",
                    "Type": "Bulky Item"
                },
                {
                    "BulkyItemCount": 2,
                    "BulkyItemType": "Basketball Set",
                    "DriverFirstName": "SA",
                    "DriverLastName": "West",
                    "Type": "Bulky Item"
                }
            ]
        },
        "ListOfLa311IllegalDumpingPickup": {},
        "ListOfLa311ManualPickup": {},
        "ListOfLa311MetalHouseholdAppliancesPickup": {},
        "ListOfLa311MoveInMoveOut": {},
        "ListOfLa311ServiceNotComplete": {},
        "QTY_10": "None",
        "QTY_6": "None",
        "QTY_7": "None",
        "QTY_8": "None",
        "QTY_9": "None",
        "QYT_1": "None",
        "QYT_2": "None",
        "QYT_3": "None",
        "QYT_4": "None",
        "QYT_5": "None",
        "RESOLUTION_CODE": "A",
        "ResolutionCode": "None",
        "SRNumber": "1-22137551",
        "UpdatedByUserLogin": "MYLA-SAN2",
        "last_edited_user": "SA"
    }
}
```

The logic of my script is adding the key:value of variables like ITEM_1 and QTY_1, I just want the values from each of these to add to the dictionaries under 'ListOfLa311BulkyItem` which are hard coded.